# PHP - header() redirect: Firebug logs 404 - why?

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-headers, firebug

I am using a PHP redirect in one of my projects. I do it like this:

```
header( 'Location: http://domain.net/?cig=warn&onum=' . $onum . '&cnum=' . $cnum . '&c=' . $c . '#Form' );
```

So you see, it's a normal use of PHP's `header()` function where some variables are included in the URL.
It's working, but testing the page with Firebug, I get this error in the console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://domain.net/?cig=warn&onum=12&cnum=73&c=ui#Form"
```

Is there actually something wrong with the way I do it or is this just Firebug being picky because of all the parameters and the anchor?

Comment: so, well, is the page found?

Comment: Yes it's working, I am just wondering why Firebug gives me that error.

Comment: Could the target location be *sending* a 404 for some reason?

Comment: ^^^ that or a firebug bug, there are numerous ways to check the headers sent.

Comment: No as it's a redirect inside the same page the target domain isn't sending a 404 back I think.

Comment: you get the same error when you copy and paste the url in to FF

Comment: Yes, but the page is found - the error only exists in the Firebug console.

Comment: so the page is just issuing a 404 header, bad page!

Comment: Does this page live within a WordPress environment? If so, WP can occasionally cause stray 404's for pages that live outside of the WP framework.

Comment: @JonahBishop Yep it's Wordpress page. Anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this page lives within a WordPress environment, you must force a 200 status code by manually setting it before your headers get sent (using the WordPress [status_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/status_header) function):

```
<?php
// This must appear before any output is sent!
status_header(200);
?>
```

You'll have to pull in the WordPress functions to get at this, obviously. The problem is that WordPress is intercepting the request before your page has a chance to process it. It cannot locate the "page" and sets a 404 response code, which is what eventually gets sent back out.

When I've had to pull in the WordPress functions in the past, I've done so by including these two lines on the page:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once("/path/to/my/site/wp-blog-header.php");
```

Now, that said, the pages I've done this with in the past have had the same look and feel as the ones in my WordPress installation. There may be a better way to pull in the functions alone; you'd have to consult the WordPress documentation to find out (I don't know if there is). How to do it properly might be a good question for the [WordPress StackExchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your explanation sounds logical to me. The problem now is, as soon as I do `include( '../../../../wp-includes/functions.php' );`, the script totally stops working. Do I need to access the Wordpress functions.php through another file?

Comment: Indeed, that way I am able to use `status_header` in the file although it lives outside the standard Wordpress files. But Firebug stills shows the 404. I tested with `function_exists`if `status_header` is available and it is, so the problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm. You might toy around with positioning that call in various places in your code. Perhaps the 404 is getting set somewhere else? The above has worked for me when I've done this sort of thing, so I'm not sure what could be going on for you. Debugging this stuff can really get tricky. You might try looking at the actual headers with one of the header extensions, or try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).